# Jump to end of specific line

Tags: c, file-io, stdio

I am trying to change my cursor position in an opened file.

```
fp = fopen("dirty", "a+");
fprintf(fp, "Text at end of file");

// seek to end of third line (eg.)

fprintf(fp, "Text at end of third line");
```

I have tried closing and reopening the file, and `fseek`, which didn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As long as you know the position of the third line, `fseek` should do the trick. Can you show us what you have that doesn't work using `fseek()`?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I discovered that I should be opening the file with r+ mode. Now `fseek(fp, 2, SEEK_SET);` will work. How might I seek right to the end of the line? Overshooting the EOL will start to overwrite the next line.

Comment: You need to know what position the end of the line is. There's no substitute for this.

Comment: Okay, I guess I'll have to figure this out. How can I approve your answer?

Comment: It is not possible simply SEEK, if undefined length of one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find a position in a file, use `fseek()`. There is no knowledge in C/C++ file handling to know about where lines start and/or end, other than in the sense that there are "end of line markers", newline (`'\n'`).

To know where a line starts or ends you have to track that yourself (e.g. by reading the file character by character with `fgetc()`, element by element with `fscanf()` or line by line `fgets()` and when you find certain important parts, use `ftell()` to save the current position.

Note that whilst it may appear that `fgets()` knows about lines, it really just reads from where you are in the file, and when the character is a newline, it stops. But there's no knowledge available about "this line is 40 characters long".

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to `fseek` to the beginning of the file, then read char by char with `getc` until you found the third newline, then `ungetc` (which can only unget exactly one character). Note however that you *cannot* insert text after the third line without overwriting the fourth.

(Inserting in the middle of a file is usually performed by copying the initial part, writing the new data, and then copying the final part.)

Comment: Thanks for that last tip. I am seeing that problem now that I have `fseek` working. Do you have any code that will solve this problem?